# How to do same js encoding?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I know there's no real way of protecting js files content but I found a way that someone did that makes it really hard for just anyone to get the original content and I hope you can help me know what's the source and how to do in the same encrypted way.

```
var cf = parent['cboxform'];
var cm = window;
var frmod = 'http://france10s.com/cbox/?';

function include(_0xce28x5, _0xce28x6) {
    head = _0xce28x6['document']['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0];
    var _0xce28x7 = _0xce28x6['document']['createElement']('script');
    _0xce28x7['setAttribute']('type', 'text/javascript');
    _0xce28x7['setAttribute']('src', _0xce28x5);
    head['insertBefore'](_0xce28x7, head['lastChild']);
};
include(frmod + 'g', cm);
include(frmod + 'cl', cm);
include(frmod + 'ft', cm);
include(frmod + 'pk', cm);
include(frmod + 'tm', cm);
include(frmod + 'm', cm);
```

The content of the includes is very hard to decrypt using anything, I know which is why I had like to know how can I do same.

Thanks

Comment: You can always minify and obfuscate your code to make it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called an [obfuscator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29). Searching for "JavaScript obfuscator" gives plenty of results, and then the results they give are truly horrible, just how you'd like, for example, here's what http://www.jsobfuscate.com/ did with your code:

`eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('6 f=e[\'h\'];6 3=i;6 2=\'k://j.d/l/?\';c 1(a,7){4=7[\'8\'][\'b\'](\'4\')[0];6 5=7[\'8\'][\'t\'](\'y\');5[\'9\'](\'v\',\'n/x\');5[\'9\'](\'w\',a);4[\'u\'](5,4[\'p\'])};1(2+\'g\',3);1(2+\'o\',3);1(2+\'q\',3);1(2+\'r\',3);1(2+\'s\',3);1(2+\'m\',3);',35,35,'|include|frmod|cm|head|_0xce28x7|var|_0xce28x6|document|setAttribute|_0xce28x5|getElementsByTagName|function|com|parent|cf||cboxform|window|france10s|http|cbox||text|cl|lastChild|ft|pk|tm|createElement|insertBefore|type|src|javascript|script'.split('|'),0,{}))`

Edit: Your sample looks very similar to http://javascriptobfuscator.com/, here's an example:

`var _0x81b5=[];function foo(_0xd99cx2){var _0xd99cx3=3;function _0xd99cx4(_0xd99cx5){alert(_0xd99cx2+_0xd99cx5+(++_0xd99cx3));} ;_0xd99cx4(10);} ;foo(2);`

Comment: Note: Obfuscating could decrease the efficiency of your code.

Comment: this one i almost got, but the includes are the hard ones which i couldnt decrypt

Comment: The code in the question is actually pretty straightforward, all it does is just loads a few scripts.

Comment: @Koterpillar, but the codes it loads are encrypted in a good way, please lte me know if you can crack it, thanks in advance

Comment: So do you want to obfuscate your code or de-obfuscate other code? If the latter, perhaps ask a different question...